# How do I get the markercluster group to work with my csv data? (Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup?)

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geospatial, markerclusterer, leaflet.markercluster

I am trying to make the markerclusters work so that when I turn on each layer, the markerclusters add together and subtract when I turn off each layer.

I had the markerclusters working when I was not using the layers, but now I'm not sure what to do. I've seen people talk about the L.featureGroup.subGroup, but I don't really know how to apply it to my code.

I'm new to Leaflet and just need some guidance on what I should do please.

Here's what it looks like when all layers are on. Note how the markers are not in the cluster groups:
[image]

Here's my code:

```
var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [34.098907, -118.327759],
      zoom: 9,
      tap: false
    });

    var light = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.'
    });

    var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 20,
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    });


    var baseLayers = {
      "Carto Light Basemap": light,
      "Stamen Terrain Basemap": terrain,
      "Satelite Basemap": googleSat,
    };

    L.control.layers(baseLayers).addTo(map)


    var engineerLayers = {}; // Create an object to hold the engineer layers

    var controlLayers = L.control.layers(null, engineerLayers, {
      position: "bottomleft",
      collapsed: false
    }).addTo(map);

 

    var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

    $.get('./data.csv', function (csvString) {
      var data = Papa.parse(csvString, { header: true, dynamicTyping: true }).data;

      // Loop through the data and create layers and markers for each engineer
      //***** MAKE SURE CSV FILE DOES NOT HAVE EXTRA LINES OF SPACE OR ELSE AN UNDEFINED LAYER WILL APPEAR*******///
      
      for (var i in data) {
        var row = data[i];
        var marker;
        var engineer = row.Engineer;

        if (!(engineer in engineerLayers)) {
          engineerLayers[engineer] = L.featureGroup();
          controlLayers.addOverlay(engineerLayers[engineer], engineer);
        }

        marker = L.circleMarker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {
          radius: 10,
          stroke: true,
          color: getColor(engineer),
          opacity: 1,
          weight: 1,
          fill: true,
          fillColor: getColor(engineer),
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).bindPopup('Plan File: ' + row.PFN + '</br>' + 'Engineer: ' + row.Engineer);
        markers.addLayer(marker);
        ;

        markers.addLayer(marker);
        marker.addTo(engineerLayers[engineer]);
      }

      map.addLayer(markers);
    });

    //must change these if engineers ever change
    function getColor(engineer) {
      switch (engineer) {
        case 'Mike':
          return 'green';
        case 'Salar':
          return 'blue';
        case 'Diego':
          return 'purple';
        case 'Saul':
          return 'orange';
        default:
          return 'black';
      }
    }
```

Here's what it looks like when all the layers are turned off. Note how there are clusters even with the layers off:

[image]

UPDATE:

So, I updated my code so that each layer now has it's own marker cluster.

What I can't figure out is how to make each of these subgroups into one parent group. What am I doing wrong?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>leaflet-map-csv</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

  <!-- For the search box -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/MarkerCluster.Default.css" />

  <!-- Load Leaflet code library - see updates at http://leafletjs.com/download.html -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.css" />

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.css" />

  <!-- Position the map with Cascading Style Sheet (CSS) -->
  <style>
    body {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
    }

    #map {
      position: absolute;
      top: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      right: 0;
      left: 0;
    }
    
    .leaflet-bottom.leaflet-left {
      left: 10px;
      bottom: 10px;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

  <!-- Insert HTML division tag to layout the map -->
  <div id="map"></div>

  <!-- Insert Javascript (.js) code to create the map -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.7.1/dist/leaflet.js"></script>

  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.markercluster/dist/leaflet.markercluster.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup/dist/leaflet.featuregroup.subgroup-src.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.3.0/papaparse.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet-control-geocoder/dist/Control.Geocoder.js"></script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/0.4.2/leaflet.draw.js"></script>

  <!-- Insert JavaScript code to create the map and add engineer layers -->
  <script>
    var map = L.map('map', {
      center: [34.098907, -118.327759],
      zoom: 9,
      tap: false
    });

    var light = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.basemaps.cartocdn.com/light_all/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
      attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>, &copy; <a href="https://carto.com/attribution">CARTO</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    var terrain = L.tileLayer('https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/terrain/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
      attribution: 'Map tiles by <a href="http://stamen.com">Stamen Design</a>, under <a href="http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/3.0">CC BY 3.0</a>. Data by <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a>, under <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">ODbL</a>.'
    });

    var googleSat = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.google.com/vt/lyrs=s&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
      maxZoom: 20,
      subdomains: ['mt0', 'mt1', 'mt2', 'mt3']
    });

    var baseLayers = {
      "Carto Light Basemap": light,
      "Stamen Terrain Basemap": terrain,
      "Satellite Basemap": googleSat,
    };

    var controlLayers = L.control.layers(baseLayers);

    var engineerLayers = {}; // Create an object to hold the engineer marker cluster groups

    $.get('./data.csv', function (csvString) {
      var data = Papa.parse(csvString, {
        header: true,
        dynamicTyping: true
      }).data;

      // Create a parent feature group
      var parentGroup = L.featureGroup.subGroup(null, []);

      // Loop through the data and create marker clusters for each engineer
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var row = data[i];
        var marker;
        var engineer = row.Engineer;

        if (!(engineer in engineerLayers)) {
          engineerLayers[engineer] = L.markerClusterGroup({
            spiderfyOnMaxZoom: false,
            showCoverageOnHover: true,
            zoomToBoundsOnClick: true
          });

          // Add the child layers to the parent group
          parentGroup.addLayer(engineerLayers[engineer]);
          controlLayers.addOverlay(engineerLayers[engineer], engineer);
        }

        marker = L.circleMarker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {
          radius: 10,
          stroke: true,
          color: getColor(engineer),
          opacity: 1,
          weight: 1,
          fill: true,
          fillColor: getColor(engineer),
          fillOpacity: 0.5
        }).bindPopup('Plan File: ' + row.PFN + '</br>' + 'Engineer: ' + row.Engineer);

        engineerLayers[engineer].addLayer(marker);
      }

      // Add the parent group to the map
      parentGroup.addTo(map);
      controlLayers.addTo(map);
    });

    // Add event listeners to handle showing and hiding markers and clusters
    controlLayers.on('overlayadd', function (eventLayer) {
      var engineer = eventLayer.name;
      if (engineer in engineerLayers) {
        engineerLayers[engineer].addTo(map);
      }
    });

    controlLayers.on('overlayremove', function (eventLayer) {
      var engineer = eventLayer.name;
      if (engineer in engineerLayers) {
        engineerLayers[engineer].removeFrom(map);
      }
    });

    // Must change these if engineers ever change
    function getColor(engineer) {
      switch (engineer) {
        case 'Mike':
          return 'green';
        case 'Salar':
          return 'blue';
        case 'Diego':
          return 'purple';
        case 'Saul':
          return 'orange';
        default:
          return 'black';
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first attempt, you add each `marker` to *both* your `markers` MarkerClusterGroup *and* your `engineerLayers[engineer]` overlay.

This results in a situation almost identical to [Leaflet markercluster markers and cluster icons both visible on load](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54485131/leaflet-markercluster-markers-and-cluster-icons-both-visible-on-load/54489073#54489073), where Markers are "simultaneously" counted in clusters *and* shown on map (or not, if the overlay is off in your case).

Indeed [`L.featureGroup.subGroup`](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup) sounds to cover your use case:

> Typical usage is to dynamically add/remove groups of markers from Marker Cluster.

Make sure to follow the [documentation](https://github.com/ghybs/Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup#quick-guide):

```js
// The Parent is the MCG
var parentGroup = L.markerClusterGroup();

for (var i in data) {
  var row = data[i];
  var engineer = row.Engineer;

  if (!(engineer in engineerLayers)) {
    // Each overlay that should actually be a part of MCG
    // should be made as a Subgroup, with the MCG as their parent
    engineerLayers[engineer] = L.featureGroup.subGroup(parentGroup, []);

    controlLayers.addOverlay(engineerLayers[engineer], engineer);
  }

  var marker = L.circleMarker([row.Latitude, row.Longitude], {});

  // Add the marker only to its overlay
  marker.addTo(engineerLayers[engineer]; 
}

map.addLayer(parentGroup);
```

> Disclaimer: I am the author of Leaflet.FeatureGroup.SubGroup

Comment: didn't know I could do that. Thank you!